# Value of the Object HtmlInputElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

In my .html file I have one button and string variable `str = "<input type=\"text\" value=\"apple\""` . When i click button i want to alert value of these string . How can i parse string to object and just use  something like `obj.val()` or `obj.value` to get it's value . I've tried `$.parseHTML(str)` . it returns me **Object HtmlInputElement** , but  i can't use `.val()` or `.value`  , even `.attr('value')` **?** Jquery is added   and no errors . Please help . Best Regards .

Comment: Can you please post your actual code.

Comment: You need to create jquery object to use `.val()` or `.attr()`, see below answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this: create jquery object from `str` and then call `.val()` on that object, see below code

```
str = "<input type=\"text\" value=\"apple\">";
var strObj = $(str);
alert(strObj.val());
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/xaetLyvr/)**

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer is helpful to you then you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you put your input in your actual html file, and give it an id (e.g. **appleInput**):

```
<input type="text" value="apple" id="appleInput"> <!-- Your input -->
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```
var str = document.getElementById("appleInput").value;
alert(str);
```